# Why can't I use scipy.linalg after importing scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

If I run the following two lines of code:

```
import numpy
numpy.linalg
```

I do not get an error, and I get the output `<module 'numpy.linalg' from /Users/...>`.

However, if I run the following two lines of code

```
import scipy
scipy.linalg
```

I get the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7ed633b28ccc> in <module>
      1 import scipy
----> 2 scipy.linalg

AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'linalg'
```

However, the following code seems to work fine:

```
import scipy.linalg
scipy.linalg
```

My question is: how come after importing `numpy`, I can use `numpy.linalg`, but I can't do the same for `scipy`?

For context, I am using numpy version 1.19.2, and I am using scipy version 1.4.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a line in "numpy/__init__.py", which is the module initialization file, that explicitly imports `linalg`:

```
from . import linalg
```

There is no such line in "scipy/__init__.py". That is why you must import `scipy.linalg` yourself.

Comment: Yes, all of us have been burned by this once upon a time, but I really don't understand why the scipy people did this.